# python string with int array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a shopping system in python for learning purposes.

I'm trying to create an array of items with prices. I am using a pick import for a gui user input. here is my code.

```
from pick import pick

## shopping system

title = 'What would you like to do: '
options = ['shop', 'increase wallet', 'exit']
option, index = pick(options, title)

def wallet_increase(value):
    wallet = 15.00
    wallet += value
    print("New wallet balance $" + str(wallet)) 

def my_shop():
    title = 'What would you like to purchase: '
    products = ['eggs', 'cheese', 'meat', 'chocolate']
    choice, index = pick(products, title)
    print(choice + " has been selected")

if option == 'increase wallet':
    value = float(input ("Wallet increase amount? $"))
    wallet_increase(value)

if option == 'shop':
    my_shop()
```

essentially what I am trying to achieve is upon the user picking a product (cheese for example). It will ultimately subtract the product price from the wallet value. I currently only have the products with no prices attached to them. I dont understand how I can achieve an array with prices linked to the products.

Comment: Might be best to use a dict to map prices to products

Comment: use dictionary `{product_name: price}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only reference code for dict you need to change as per your requirement

```
from pick import pick

## shopping system

title = 'What would you like to do: '
options = ['shop', 'increase wallet', 'exit']
option, index = pick(options, title)
wallet=15
def wallet_increase(value,wallet):
    wallet += value
    print("New wallet balance $" + str(wallet)) 

def wallet_decrese(value,wallet):
    wallet-=value
    print("New wallet balance $" + str(wallet)) 

def my_shop():
    title = 'What would you like to purchase: '
    products ={'eggs':10,'cheese':20,'meat':5,'chocolate':12}
    choice=pick(list(products.keys()),title)
    wallet_decrese(products[choice[0]],wallet)
    print(choice[0] + " has been selected")

if option == 'increase wallet':
    value = float(input ("Wallet increase amount? $"))
    wallet_increase(value)

if option == 'shop':
    my_shop()
```

Comment: @patrickGold just give upvote and mark as an answer  it will help